# Introduce an 2D Array into a Function c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

Good morning to everyone, i know there is so many forms to pass an Array in to a function, and there are so many potst about this. But even reading this post i can not pass my array to the function. 
When I call the function on main, it appears an error as it shows on the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int row = 5;
int column=20;
void dimensions (int [20]);

int main (){

int *matriuprova[column];
for (int i= 0; i<column;i++){

    matriuprova[i] = new int [row];

    dimensions(matriuprova);// <-- here is the error:
        //main.cpp:14:31: error: cannot convert 'int**' to 'int*' 
        //for argument '1' to 'void dimensions(int*)'

}//end of for loop

return 0;
}//end of main

void dimensions (int *matriuprova [20]){
        //function code
         }
```

I have followed this link: **[Passing a 2D array to a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function)**

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Your declaration and definition of `dimensions` are incompatible.

Comment: As  column` is not const, you use *VLA* (Varaible length array) extension for `matriuprova`

Comment: Why not use `std::vector` or `std::array`?

Answer (score 2):

You have wrong forward declaration of `dimensions`.

Change

```
    void dimensions (int [20]);
```

to

```
    void dimensions (int* [20]);
```

Comment: And note that `void dimensions (int* [20]);` is the same as `void dimensions (int**);`. The latter is less confusing.

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't think an array of pointers is the same as a pointer to a pointer...

Comment: @jiggunjer A function parameter `int*[N]` is a pointer to pointer, not an array of pointers. When I said they are the same, I really meant it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int row = 5;
int column=20;
void dimensions (int* [20]);

int main (){

int *matriuprova[column];
for (int i= 0; i<column;i++){

    matriuprova[i] = new int [row];

    dimensions(matriuprova);// <-- here is the error:
        //main.cpp:14:31: error: cannot convert 'int**' to 'int*' 
        //for argument '1' to 'void dimensions(int*)'

}//end of for loop

return 0;
}//end of main

void dimensions (int *matriuprova [20]){
        //function code
         }
```

It's like the compiler said. It found the definition which was `void dimensions(int [20])`, which doesn't match your matrix.
Correct the definition and it resolves the problem.